# too many redirect while redirecting to SSL

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect to https but it doesn't working with the code below
which i put it at the beginning of index.php

```
 <?php 
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == ""){
   $redirect = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   header("Location: $redirect");

 }
```

Comment: try without `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == ""`

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

of PHP

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on') {
    if(!headers_sent()) {
        header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
        header(sprintf(
            'Location: https://%s%s',
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        ));
        exit();
    }
}
```